# Python .join interation not working as expected

Tags: python

I'm writing a fun script to offer up pizza toppings, so I run the following code:

```
import random

# initializing toppings list  
toppings_list = ["pepperoni", "cheese", "sausage", "peppers", "onions", "olives", "green onion", "mushroom", "anchovies", "bacon", "pancetta", "tomatoes", "garlic"] 

# get a random number of toppings on this pizza
number_toppings = random.randint(0, len(toppings_list))

# get set of random toppings
for i in range(number_toppings):
    pizza_string = ", ".join(random.choice(toppings_list))

# return a whole pizza with a random set of toppings 
print ("Your " + str(number_toppings) + " topping pizza is : " + pizza_string)
```

But the output is:

`Your 5 topping pizza is : g, a, r, l, i, c`

and

`Your 9 topping pizza is : g, a, r, l, i, c`

and

`Your 12 topping pizza is : o, n, i, o, n, s`

I am missing something basic here, but why are each letter of the toppings list returned separately? If I change the last line as below, each topping is returned as a whole item from the list. So what am I doing wrong on the .join command?

```
import random

# initializing toppings list  
toppings_list = ["pepperoni", "cheese", "sausage", "peppers", "onions", "olives", "green onion", "mushroom", "anchovies", "bacon", "pancetta", "tomatoes", "garlic"] 

# get a random number of toppings on this pizza
number_toppings = random.randint(0, len(toppings_list))

# get set of random toppings
for i in range(number_toppings):
    pizza_string = ", ".join(random.choice(toppings_list))

# return a whole pizza with a random set of toppings 

# print ("Your " + str(number_toppings) + " topping pizza is : " + pizza_string)
print ("Your " + str(number_toppings) + " topping pizza is : " + random.choice(toppings_list))
```

The results are:

`Your 7 topping pizza is : pancetta`

and

`Your 6 topping pizza is : anchovies`

and

`Your 5 topping pizza is : green onion`

Comment: random.choice(toppings_list) gives u a random string from the list, lets say it is "garlic", and join operator takes "garlic", which is a chr list, i.e. ["g","a","r","l","i","c"]  and adds "," to it, it becomes "g,a,r,l,i,c"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

```py
import random

# initializing toppings list  
toppings_list = ["pepperoni", "cheese", "sausage", "peppers", "onions", "olives", "green onion", "mushroom", "anchovies", "bacon", "pancetta", "tomatoes", "garlic"] 

# get a random number of toppings on this pizza
number_toppings = random.randint(0, len(toppings_list) - 1)

# get set of random toppings
pizza_string = ", ".join(random.sample(toppings_list, k=number_toppings))

# return a whole pizza with a random set of toppings 
print ("Your " + str(number_toppings) + " topping pizza is : " + pizza_string)
```

Comment: Just to add to this answer, `random.choices` is with replacement (i.e. you can get the same topping twice). If you don't want that then use `random.sample`

Comment: Thank you Balaji and ScootCork, just what I was looking for.